# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, lambda, promise, gatsby, netlify

my app is working fine on localhost but giving me an error

*Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 this is my index file*

why it's not working on the server someone guid,e please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally see this when the server returns an error (e.g. a 500 server error). The problem is that the server is returning *non Json response ex: a plain text or sometimes even HTML* and then the client app is trying to parse JSON from it thus throwing the error. I would recommend opening the chrome dev tools, navigating to the Network tab, refreshing the page, and then look for the request in question and see what is actually getting returned from the server.